# React Context with notifications list

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-context, react-component

I am using a context to hold a list of all my notifications. When a notification is created, the context's state is set to a new list with this new notification added. The app re-renders, loops, and renders all the notifications to the screen. When a notification is due, the context is updated to filter out that notification.

However, the notifications have an animation so they can slide to the right before they are removed, which I made so it yields to update the notifications list until the animation is done. Unfortunately, if I close multiple notifications at once, some of them comeback because they are all simultaneously trying to update with an old list.

I don't know where to go.

Notification Context:

> ```
> import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react"
> import Notification from "../components/Notification"
>
> const NotificationsContext = createContext()
> const SetNotificationsContext = createContext()
>
> export function useNotifications() {
>     return useContext(NotificationsContext)
> }
>
> export function useSetNotifications() {
>     return useContext(SetNotificationsContext)
> }
>
> export default function NotificationsProvider({children}) {
>     const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([])
>
>     return (
>         <NotificationsContext.Provider value={notifications}>
>             <SetNotificationsContext.Provider value={setNotifications}>
>                 <div className="notifications-wrapper">
>                     {notifications.map(note => {
>                         return <Notification key={note.id} note={note}/>
>                     })}
>                 </div>
>                 {children}
>             </SetNotificationsContext.Provider> 
>         </NotificationsContext.Provider>
>     )
> }
> ```

Notification Component:

> ```
> import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
> import { useNotifications, useSetNotifications } from '../contexts/NotificationsProvider'
> import useInterval from '../hooks/useInterval'
>
> function Notification({note}) {
>     const noteRef = useRef()
>
>     const notifications = useNotifications()
>     const setNotifications = useSetNotifications()
>
>     const [width, setWidth] = useState(0)
>     const [delay, setDelay] = useState(null)
>
>     // grow progress bar
>     useInterval(
>         useCallback(
>             () => setWidth(oldWidth => oldWidth + 1), 
>             [setWidth]
>         ), 
>     delay)
>
>     // sliding left animation
>     useEffect(() => {
>         // console.log("slided left")
>         noteRef.current.onanimationend = () => {
>             noteRef.current.classList.remove("slide-left")
>             noteRef.current.onanimationend = undefined
>         }
>
>         noteRef.current.classList.add("slide-left")
>     }, [])
>
>     const handleStartTimer = useCallback(() => {
>         console.log("timer STARTED")
>         setDelay(10)
>     }, [setDelay])
>
>     const handlePauseTimer = useCallback(() => {
>         console.log("timer PAUSED")
>         setDelay(null)
>     }, [setDelay])
>
>     // filter off notification and sliding right animation
>     const handleCloseNotification = useCallback(() => {
>         console.log("slided right / removed notification")
>         handlePauseTimer()
>         noteRef.current.onanimationend = () => {
>             setNotifications([...notifications.filter(listNote => listNote.id !== note.id)])
>         }
>         noteRef.current.classList.add("slide-right")
>     }, [note.id, notifications, setNotifications, handlePauseTimer])
>
>     // notification is due
>     useLayoutEffect(() => {
>         if (width >= noteRef.current.clientWidth - 10) {
>             handleCloseNotification()
>         }
>     }, [width, handleCloseNotification, handlePauseTimer])
>
>     // start timer when notification is created
>     useEffect(() => {
>         handleStartTimer()
>
>         return handlePauseTimer
>     }, [handleStartTimer, handlePauseTimer])
>     
>     return (
>         <div ref={noteRef} className={`notification-item ${note.type === "SUCCESS" ? "success" : "error"}`}
>         onMouseOver={handlePauseTimer} onMouseLeave={handleStartTimer}>
>             <button onClick={handleCloseNotification} className='closing-button'>✕</button>
>             <strong>{note.text}</strong>
>             <div className='notification-timer' style={{"width":`${width}px`}}></div>
>         </div>
>     )
> }
>
> export default Notification
> ```

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your set notifications line to:

```
setNotifications(prevNotifications => [...prevNotifications.filter(listNote => listNote.id !== note.id)])
```

This will ensure you never use a stale value.